# Integration with vectors

Tags: integration, vectors

I am trying to solve below integration 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\hat{k_{i}}{e^{i\textbf{k}.\textbf{R}}}dk$$

here $R,l$ are constants and $\hat{k_{i}}$ is a unit vector of $\textbf{k}_i$. And as usual $\hat{k_{i}}=\frac{\textbf{k}_{i}}{k_{i}}$,$\hat{R}=\frac{\textbf{R}}{R}$ 
$$\textbf{k}=\textbf{k}_i \hat{i}+\textbf{k}_j \hat{j}$$
$$\textbf{R}=\textbf{R}_i \hat{i}+\textbf{R}_j \hat{j}$$

I have no idea how to simplify this expression and get rid of the unit vector. 
I saw that this integration can be solved taking $$\frac{1}{ik_{j}}\nabla_{j}\int \ e^{i\textbf{k}.\textbf{R}}$$ If I can show above relationship, then I will be able to handle the integration part. Any help on this is really appriciated

Comment: I suppose $i = \sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: And what is $k$ without the cap? Just another constant?

Comment: @Gummybears it is the unit vector of vector $\textbf{k}$. And as usual $\hat{k}=\frac{\textbf{k}}{k}$

Comment: The unit vector $\hat k$ is independent of the magnitude of $\vec k$.  Inasmuch as the integration is over $k=|\vec k|$, we can simply pull the unit vector out of the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't get rid of the unit vector. The question here would be is the unit vector constant itself ? for example the position vector in physics:

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{r} = x(t) \hat{i} + y(t) \hat{j} + z(t) \hat{k}
\end{equation}

the unit vectors here are indeed constant so when integrating they can just be pulled out of the integral. Now in alternate coordinate representations for specific types of motion( i.e. rotation) we use curvilinear(polar) unit vectors which do change with respect to time.

So if the unit vector is constant just pull it out of the integral. If the unit vector is not constant you may want to use integration by parts and have your answer in terms of its derivative possibly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. in this case the unit vector is not constant.And my issue is handling a non-constant unit vector.

Comment: do you have any extra information about it ?  for example  : $\hat{k} = \hat{i}k^{2}  + k\hat{j}$ where both $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ are independant of $k$

Comment: thanks for the comment. Yes I have modified the question now with more details

Comment: hmm you have bassically said that $\hat{k_{i}} = \hat{i}$ unless $\boldsymbol{k}=\boldsymbol{k_{i}}$ ? also am I right in assuming $k_i$ and $k_j$ are scalar functions of $k$?.

Comment: yes you are correct. I think I found a similar question in a book. They have taken partial derivative w.r.t $R$. However, I am having few issues in solving that equation.So I posted another question related to this. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425022/solving-a-gradient-operation-which-involves-unit-vectors. If I can solve that question I can tackle this one easily